# Open jquery Fancybox in b-modal VueJS

Tags: jquery, vue.js, fancybox, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to open a simple fancybox in a bootstrap modal.
When i open only simple fancybox:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="http://samplepdf.com/sample.pdf">Open pdf</a>
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
  width  : 600,
  height : 300,
  type   :'iframe'
});
```

it works good like this, my PDF is displayed in a lightbox. 
When i try to put my fancybox in a b-modal:

```
<b-modal
  v-model="modalShow"
  @ok="submit">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <a
      class="fancybox"
      href="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf">
      Open
    </a>
  </div>
</b-modal>
```

when i click on "Open", my PDF is opened in a new page like a simple link href.
I would like to open the fancybox and display my PDF normaly in my modal.
Some ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe this is because `$(".fancybox").fancybox()` is executed before that element exists?

Comment: Thank you, i added: $(".fancybox").fancybox({ width : 900, height : 450 }); in my @shown and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as @Janis said it might be the case that fancybox executes before it can find the link .
One workaround is to open the b-modal with a method and execute the fancybox there.

So give your modal a ref like `ref="myModal"` and remove v-modal like:

```
   <b-modal ref="myModal" > 
   </b-modal>
```

Create a method showModal in `methods`

Inside the showModal function write the following code

```
 methods:{
   showModal:function(){
     this.$refs.myModal.show();
     $(".fancybox").fancybox({
      width  : 900,
      height : 450
     });
   }
 }
```

Comment: I have a working example here `https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RYyWPr` i didnt use your pdf because codepen runs from https and your pdf is in http and it cant be loaded

Comment: Thank you, i added:
 
     $(".fancybox").fancybox({
      width  : 900,
      height : 450
     }); in my @shown and it worked!